# Fade in effect only after Login on main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a transition between my login page and the main page of the site. However, I end up fading in the main page on each call within the site. I understand why but I can't figure out how I can set the effect only to happen when calling the main page after the login screen.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $("body").hide();
        $("body").fadeIn(10000);
    </script>
   <div> Hello World!</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to build a transition between my login page and the main page of the site. However, I end up fading in the main page on each call within the site. I understand why but I can't figure out how I can set the effect only to happen when calling the main page after the login screen.

**Main Page:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $("body").hide();
        $("body").fadeIn(1000);
    </script>
    <div> Hello World!</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Login Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn float-right login_btn" id="loginbutton">Login</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("loginbutton").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "./pages/mainpage.html";
        };
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide a complete fiddle with main and login page so we can provide a proper answer without having to write a full example

Comment: well i dont see the reason to use hide() on body while you are already doing fadeIn which doing all the trick

Comment: I added the loginpage to the initial post. fadeIn() did not work when hide() was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if(document.referrer == "http://localhost:65434/Home/Login")
    {
            $("body").hide();
            $("body").fadeIn(1000);
    }    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to set up a localhost for this? I could not get this to work with the filepath only. `<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (document.referrer == "C:/loginpage.html") {
                $("body").hide();
                $("body").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div> Hello World!</div>

</body>`

Comment: Console.log document.referrer and then put that in the if statement

Comment: log stays empty on document.referrer while document.URL returns the filepath

Comment: document.referrer returns the entire URL, including the protocol (like http://). If the current document was not opened through a link (for example, through a bookmark), an empty string is returned.

Comment: Sorry, that was too quick. Of course I'm running into the same problem and changing document.referrer to document.url is not a working solution. I replaced the login button with `<a href="./pages/mainpage.html">Login</a>` but still no console output on document.referrer...

Comment: Me being a noob, I finally resolved this issue by adding a parameter to the mainpage-call reflink and catched it in the if clause above with document.URL == "filepathLink+Parameter". Thank you all!